# Chaining forEachOf in async.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async.js

Using async.js for the first time and feeling like I'm just totally missing something as I got to a working state through brute force and I'm not confident it'll work with any other set of data. Would love to know if there's something I'm not seeing here.

I have an array of objects each of which contains an array. I want to iterate through the subarray, use it in a call to mongo, and do something with the results after they're all returned. The data looks like this:

**Data**

```
productVersions: [
    versionA: {
        relevantField: [
            {
                relevantId: value
            },
            {
                relevantId: value
            }
        ]
    },
    versionB: {
        relevantField: [
            {
                relevantId: value
            },
            {
                relevantId: value
            },
            {
                relevantId: value
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

In the code I want to make a call for each object in `relevantField` in `productVersions` and after all calls have been made for both versions do some stuff with the results. The code looks like this:

**Code**

```
async.forEachOf(productVersions, function(version, versionIndex, versionCallback){
    async.forEachOf(relevantField, function(object, objectIndex, objectCallback){
        Users.findById(object.relevantId, function(err, model){
            // get some information from mongo
            objectCallback();
        });
    }, function(){
        versionCallback();
    });
}, function(err){
    // Do something with all the results
});
```

This happens to be functional right now but I have a feeling that's because of timing and luck and if the calls were slower of if there were more data it wouldn't work. Am I doing anything wrong here? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

As a `async` maintainer looks fine to me, although my personal preference would have me separate these functions out. You can also consider using waterfall/series to manage this flow

```
function processRelevantField(object, objectIndex, objectCallback){
    Users.findById(object.relevantId, function(err, model){
        // get some information from mongo
        objectCallback();
    });
}

function processVersion(version, versionIndex, versionCallback){
    async.forEachOf(relevantField, processRelevantField, function(){
        versionCallback();
    });
}

async.forEachOf(productVersions, processVersion, function(err){
    // Do something with all the results
});
```